# How to create the switch button in a flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In flutter, how to create a switch button and text in a row. I tried but didn't get what I wanted. And how to remove the tag inside the custom switch.

[image: Please see here]

```dart
import 'package:custom_switch/custom_switch.dart';

bool status = true;

    Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                child: CustomSwitch(
                  activeColor: Color(0xff771ae1),
                  value: status,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
            Text('Value : $status', style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20.0
            ),)
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: if you are using `custom_switch` it is 3y old

Comment: Can you send an example with a flutter switch?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SwitchListTile`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SwitchListTile-class.html) widget. For your case, you need to use `CupertinoSwitch`.

```dart
CupertinoListTile(
    title: Text("title"),
    trailing: CupertinoSwitch(
      value: true,
      thumbColor: Colors.white,
      activeColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      // trackColor: ,
      
      onChanged: (value) {},
    )),
```

[image]